# Fast select by category and price range in large mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select a random product from large MySQL table(~9000000 rows, 4.5GiB) with specific category ID and price range.

The solution I am using now takes about 30 seconds to complete request.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT MAX(id) FROM `products` WHERE category = $cat AND price >= $price_min AND price <= $price_max");
$f = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$max_id = $f[0];
$random_id = rand(0, $max_id);
mysqli_free_result($query);

$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `products` id=$random_id LIMIT 1");
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Is it possible to optimize the request?

Comment: First you need to optimize your table structure with proper indexing.

Comment: Please run your query with EXPLAIN and post the result here.

Comment: Indexes are your friend here.

Comment: Also, please look into using prepared statements to inject `$cat`, `$price_min` and `$price_max`.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that the second query will return a row, if there are any gaps in the id values. And the second query doesn't give any guarantee that the row that is returned will have a specific category or price range. The only guarantee we have is that the `id` value on the row it returns will be less than or equal to the `id` value returned by the first query, but it can be from any category or in any price range.

Comment: @TsarN could you verify that you do NOT want to limit your second query to receive a product in your chosen category and in the set price range, but rather just with a lower ID and the latest that does?

Answer (score 1):

To get some speed, you'll need to look into making sure `category` has an index.

But you can cut out a query if you use this:

```
$query = mysqli_query(
    $db,
    "
        SELECT *
        FROM `products`
        WHERE
            `category` = $cat
            AND `price` BETWEEN $price_min AND $price_max
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
    "
);

$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The most appropriate index for this query would likely be **`... ON products (category, price)`**.  (The query pattern here addresses a potential  issue with a "missing" id value in the OP code, with the second query not finding a row.) +1

Comment: This result from this query different from the original in a significant way... this query will only return a row that satisfies the predicates on `category` and `price`. The second query in OP isn't restricted in that way, it can return *any* row with an `id` value less than the `MAX(id)` returned by the first query. Which is a significant difference.

Comment: @spencer7593 I don't see how returning any random row is different than returning any random row with an `id` <= the MAX id. There cannot be any rows with a `id` greater than the MAX, so it's superfluous. He's using the MAX id to generate a random number in PHP, this isn't required in SQL. The original query the OP posted did restrict on `category` and `price` as well in the second query. In it's current form, I think the OP has made an error (the original version of the second query didn't have the generated random id restriction, so it's more than likely an editing error).

Comment: A further downside in generating a random number in PHP is that the row that it pertains to might have been deleted.

Comment: OP original query gets MAX(id) for rows that meet specific criteria. Then OP gets a random value between 0 and that maximum id value, and then attempts to pull a row with that id from the table. (And that id value might not exist.) The main point is that OP second query has *no guarantee* that the row will have a particular category or price. The query in this answer will only return a row with a specific category and price range. I was just pointing out that there's a fairly big difference between this query, and what the OP code is doing (and what it's doing is very strange.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan for the query. Make sure that MySQL is making use of an appropriate index to satisfy the query.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

An appropriate index for this query would have `category` as a leading column, followed by `price`, and including the `id` column.

As an example:

```
CREATE INDEX products_IX1 ON products (category, price, id);
```

With that index in place, we'd expect the `EXPLAIN` output to show that MySQL is performing a range scan operation on the index, using the first two columns (as indicated by `key_len` column.) We also expect the EXPLAIN output to show "Using index" in the Extra column, since the index is a "covering" index for the query.

---

**NOTE**

This is not related to the question you asked, but...

The code example is *vulnerable* to **SQL Injection**. Potentially unsafe values that are incorporated into the text of a SQL statement *must* be properly escaped.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

A better pattern is to make use of **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

Comment: My knowledge of mysql indexes is very limited, but by including `price` and `id`, won't the index be just as large as the table?

Comment: It might be. But OP is reporting average row size of 536 bytes. (Storage for the table divided by number or rows.) We don't know how many columns are in the table, how large they are. With an index on boht of those columns, it's likely that MySQL can eliminate vast swaths of rows that would need to be checked... with an index on just category, MySQL is going to have to visit the data page in the underlying table to check price. But with the price column in the index, MySQL can use a range scan operation on the index pages; with the id column also available, no lookups to the data page.